# Is it possible to set head image for each roster item?

Tags: gwt, ejabberd

I am using [EmiteGWT](https://github.com/EmiteGWT/emite) as client, but no any method is available on it model `RosterItem` to get head image,so the question is: is it possible to add header image for each roster item ejabberd server side?

Comment: Are you asking how to add a image for each person within a roster?

Comment: yes,only name available right now